# Certain websites turns black in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-explorer

I have a Windows 7 machine and I'm using IE. On certain websites, the entire frame will just go black. Like on site [www.politiken.dk](http://www.politiken.dk) – as you can see it's a newspaper site. And I bet you can see the site correctly.

The entire website is pitch black. I still have the menu on top, etc. but the website isn't there.

Uninstalling Flash didn't help.

Comment: This would indicate the problem more then likely is with the website and the version of IE you are using.  Since you didn't provide what version of IE we cannot help you.

Comment: Oliver Salzburg.. it specifically says I'm not to ask questions in responds on the post you call duplicate.. yet it doesn't answer my question.. so please elaborate how I*m suppose to move forward if I'm not allowed to add to the other post...

Comment: I've reopened the question for the moment, but please [edit] it to at least include the version of Internet Explorer you're using.

Comment: @Allan: try the following: with the Start Menu open, type 'int' without quotes and in the search results you should see **Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)** - click it to run IE in Safe Mode. If you still have the same problem then you can at least rule out add-ons being the cause. I'd also try changing your Windows theme to something else just in case your current one is corrupt - it can apparently affect Internet Explorer in strange ways.

Comment: Or just try Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As asked repeatedly above, which IE version?

In any case, try `Tools / Internet Options / Advanced tab / Reset` and see if that helps.